# How to get insights metrics Facebook Graph API?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I do as below

```
import urllib
import json
import facebook
import requests 
import pandas as pd

page_id = 'page_id'
access_token = 'EAACEdEose0cBAHD2v11LX0.......'
base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12"
node = "/" + page_id
parameters = "/insights/?metric=page_consumptions&period=day&since=2018-03-30&until=2018-04-30&access_token=%s" 
url = base + node + parameters
metrics = requests.get(url).json()
metrics
```

And  I get empty `data`

```
{'data': [],
 'paging': {'next': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/
```

Or I do like this

```
base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12"
node = "/" + page_id
parameters = "?fields=insights.metric(page_consumptions)&period=day&since=2018-03-30&until=2018-04-30&access_token=%s"

url = base + node + '/feed'+ parameters+'&limit=10'
metrics = requests.get(url).json()
metrics
```

And I get just id's of posts

```
{'data': [{'id': '651703178310339_1036305106516809'},
  {'id': '651703178310339_1036057803208206'},
  {'id': '651703178310339_1035981129882540'},
  {'id': '651703178310339_1034909163323070'},
  {'id': '651703178310339_1034810636666256'},
  {'id': '651703178310339_1034675570013096'},
  {'id': '651703178310339_1034390016708318'},
  {'id': '651703178310339_1034167626730557'},
  {'id': '651703178310339_1033286533485333'},
  {'id': '651703178310339_1032920266855293'}],
 'paging': {'cursors':
```

what i do wrong?
P.S.
I correctly get another content like this

```
base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12"
node = "/" + page_id
parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % access_token

until = '&since=2016-01-30&until=2018-04-30'
url = base + node +'/feed'+  parameters+'&limit=100'
pages = requests.get(url).json()
pages
```

Comment: is it your page? are you using a page token of that page? does that token include the correct permissions?

Comment: Yes, I get another content correctly for ample just feed

Comment: feed: can be read even if the page is not yours. insights: can only be read if you manage the page. so, getting feed post ids does not mean you are using the correct token and permissions for getting insights.